# Pretty print a double number in a fixed number of chars

Tags: c, printf

What is the simplest solution to print a double (printf) in C so that:

1. exactly N characters are used (will be around 6) for all double numbers (nan and infinities are handled separately), positive and negative alike (+ or - always as first char);
2. decimal representation ('.' always present) is used as long as the numeric chars are not all 0 (i.e. too small number) or the decimal point is the last of the N char (i.e too big number). Otherwise switch to scientific representation, always occupying exactly N chars.

All the solutions I can think of seem quite involved, any idea to obtain this result easily (efficiency is not a concern here) ?

Thanks!

Comment: We're not here to develop algorithms for you. What you've provided is basically a homework assignment, with a "do this for me" insinuation from you.

Comment: Show what you have tried, why it is not correct, and what you need more information on. http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/printf/ would be a start.

Comment: I was just wondering whether I missed a configuration of printf's formatting flags that would results in what I want with a single printf call. That would be 'simplest possible', no insinuation here from my side...

Comment: @pmg I haven't seen that before. Is there documentation on it? What compilers support it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could not find a way to do this via a single printf call, here is my solution.

At least 9 chars must be used as (with +- in front) that's the minimum amount of chars for scientific notation (for example: +1.0E-002). In the following I consider the case of 9 chars. The following two formats are used based on the conditions reported below:

Scientific format '%+.1e':

- chars 4 to 9 as per decimal format are 0 and the number is not identical to 0 (i.e. too small for decimal)
- the '.' char is not present between char 3 and char 8 as per decimal format (i.e. too large for decimal)

Decimal format '%+.6f':

- Infinite or nan
- All other cases

It's easy to adapt to a representation longer than 9 chars by changing the constants above.